# Encountered Attribute Error "NoneType" Object has no attribute "memberID"

Tags: python

I have tried to set it to None. But it still doesn't work. It works separately as a Class. But once called to work with another class it doesn't work. I have edited to show code instead. It keeps popping up Attribute error.

`````
class Flight:
     def __init__(self,golfers):
        self._golfers = golfers
        self._idlist = []
        for x in self._golfers:
            if self.searchGolfer(x.memberID) is not None:
                self._idlist.append(x.memberID)
            else:
                raise GolfingException("Duplicate Passenger")
        if len(self._idlist)<3 or len(self._idlist)>4:
            raise GolfingException("Flight can only consist of 3 or 4 golfers")
        elif Golfer.getMembershipStatus == False:
            raise GolfingException("Golfer {Golfer} has inactive membership")
 def golfer(self):
        return self._golfers


    def searchGolfer(self,memberID):
        if(memberID not in self._idlist):
            return memberID
        return None

    def getGolfersID(self):
        return self._idlist
    
    def getWeekendEligibility(self):
        for golfers in self._golfers:
            if golfers.membership== "Basic" or golfers.getMembershipStatus() == False:
                return False 

        return True


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._idlist}"


Class golfClub
         club1 = Golfclub(cfilename,course,trued)
                club1.setupGolfers("Golfers")
                print(club1.searchGolfers(21))
                #f1 = Flight([club1.searchGolfers(1),club1.searchGolfers(3), club1.searchGolfers(11),club1.searchGolfers(16)])
                #f2 = Flight([club1.searchGolfers(8), club1.searchGolfers(18), club1.searchGolfers(17)])
                #f3 = Flight([club1.searchGolfers(9), club1.searchGolfers(27), club1.searchGolfers(24)])
                #print(f1)
               # print(club1.searchGolfers(21))
                #club1.addBooking("07:28",f1)
                #club1.addBooking("07:48",f2)
                #club1.addBooking("07:58",f3)
                menu()
                return                            ````
`````

Comment: It's interesting that you chose to show us code that did not cause the problem.  The problem is in the `Flight.__init__` function, which we don't see.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)